# The wrong focus in the cold

Tags: film, focus, 35mm, manual-focus, cold

I took pictures with a "Start" film camera and, accordingly, 35mm. When photographing indoors, everything is fine, but only i take this camera outside in severe frost (below -15 ° C), the focus disappears in all pictures. I don't understand why this is happening (The focus was set correctly when photographing). Is this a feature of the camera? I am attaching a photo: [image: The photo taken in cold]

Comment: Are you sure the problem is focus? It looks more like condensation is fogging the front of your lens. There's also a lot of camera movement due to the slow exposure duration.

Comment: @MichaelC C by the way, yes, it is possible that the factors of lens fogging and prolonged exposure (the shutter mechanism could probably freeze in the cold, which caused the shutter to close slowly) combined together.

Comment: The longer exposure time is more likely a result of the low light levels in the scene. It's obviously early evening, rather than midday.

Comment: What camera are you referring to? Can you provide a link please? Is it one of these models? [http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Start_35](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Start_35)

Comment: @osullic camera "start" 1963 (made in USSR) https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82_(%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82)

Comment: Do you remember what kind of shutter speeds you were using? It's not impossible that the shutter got stuck open in the cold and that caused camera shake. It can happen with old, dried-up lubricants. I have a LOMO Smena that does that.

Answer (score 2):

While first impression would be that the focus is wrong because of how uniform the blur is this is clearly not the case.

1. Point light sources are not blurred uniformly and are obviously blurred my camera shaking around. If camera is shaking around some fixed point in space slowly it will look uniform at first glance.
2. There is no difference in blurriness between foreground and background.
3. I have no idea what "starter" camera is but does it even indicate the shutter speed? Rule of thumb is that you should not use longer than 1/(35mm-equivalent focal length) exposure.

Comment: 2. Would be a good indication of condensation.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it has a rangefinder (which is VERY strange for an SLR which usually would have a split prism). This means the part used to check the focus is not the lens and as a result extreme cold can probably put them out of sync by raw thermal contraction.

A split prism effectively turns the opposite sides of the lens into sides of a rangefinder and stays in sync since it uses the lens.

Comment: [The camera has a split prism.](https://camerapedia.fandom.com/wiki/Start_(SLR)) Also, I very much doubt thermal contraction would have this drastic an effect on the focusing distance.